# Text file to CSV conversion with columns

Tags: python, csv, text

I have a text file with the following structure. The first line is the heading and the next line defines the two (nm and sigma) column names. How can I convert this to csv files and save them? Furthermore, if I have 100 text files in this format, what's the most efficient way to automate this process?

*HCOOH; Nagakura et al.; 298K; gas-phase*

nm   sigma(cm2/molecule) x 10-18

154     8.680

155  9.180

156     9.480

157  9.670

158  9.790

159  9.730

160  9.520

Comment: What have you tried?  This is an easy task.  What are you going to do with the files?  Load them into Excel?

Comment: @TimRoberts I want to build a machine learning model  on those data. Each file corresponds to one sample and corresponding data are as given by the two columns.

Comment: Then why do you need a CSV?  I'm not saying it's necessarily a bad idea, but if you can read this format to create a CSV, then you can read this format to create your model.  Right?

Comment: Yes you are right. But I thought it would be a good idea to keep all the files as CSV. There will be like 50,000 samples, so 50k documents. I have experience with ML/DL but struggling with preparing the data part. And also I did try and wanted to see what would be a better/efficient solution, hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas` Python library for this purpose.

In order to read the text file ans save it as a `csv`, you can do this:

```py
import pandas as pd

def txt_to_csv(pathToTxtFile, pathToCsvFile):
    # reading the txt file
    df = pd.read_csv(<pathToTxtFile>, skiprows=1, sep=' ')

    # renaming columns
    new_col_name = f'{df.columns[1]} {df.columns[2]} {df.columns[3]}'
    df.rename(columns={df.columns[1]: new_col_name}, inplace=True)

    # dropping extra columns
    df = df.drop(columns=[df.columns[2], df.columns[3]])

    # saving as csv
    df.to_csv(<pathToCsvFile>, index=False)
```

In order to automate this for several files, you can store them all in a single folder, then loop over them and call the above function `txt_to_csv` in the loop, kinda like this:

```py
import os

for txtfile in os.listdir("<pathToFolder>"):
    if txtfile.lower().endswith(".txt"):
        txt_to_csv(txtfile, os.path.splitext(txtfile)[0]+".csv")
```

This script will save them all with the same filename but in `.csv` format in the same folder

Answer (score 1):

if the headers vary from file to file, you will have to adjust. also, I am new to multi-threading and it might be overkill for this.

https://onlinegdb.com/5S2R-yjpD

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def worker(file, csv_file):
    print(f'converting file: {file} -> {csv_file}')
    with open(file, newline=None) as IN, open(csv_file, 'w', newline=None) as OUT:
        next(IN) # throwaway first line
        headers = next(IN).strip().split(maxsplit=1) # adjust if files vary
        rows = (row for row in csv.reader(IN, delimiter=' '))
        csv.writer(OUT).writerows((headers, *rows))
    print(f'done converting file: {file} -> {csv_file}')


with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as e:
    # adjust your path accordingly
    for file in Path('.').glob('*.txt'):
        csv_file = f'{file.stem}.csv'
        e.submit(worker, file, csv_file)
```